# How do I make my boolean column in ag-grid show checkboxes

Tags: datagrid, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a boolean column in my grid which is currently displaying 'true' or 'false' but I want it to show a checkbox instead.
How should I do this.
We are using ag-grid 25 with Angular and Adaptable.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own [cell renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/cell-rendering) that renders a checkbox instead of a string. Below is an example:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from '@ag-grid-community/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'checkbox-renderer',
  template: `
    <input 
      type="checkbox" 
      (click)="checkedHandler($event)"
      [checked]="params.value"
    />
`,
})
export class CheckboxRenderer implements ICellRendererAngularComp, OnDestroy {
  private params: any;

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
  }

  checkedHandler(event) {
      let checked = event.target.checked;
      let colId = this.params.column.colId;
      this.params.node.setDataValue(colId, checked);
  }
}
```

```
import { CheckboxRenderer } from "./checkbox-renderer.component";
```

```
this.frameworkComponents = {
  checkboxRenderer: CheckboxRenderer
};
```

#### [Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-binding-boolean-checkboxes?embed=1&file=src/app/checkbox-renderer.component.ts)

#### Resource

- https://blog.ag-grid.com/binding-boolean-values-to-checkboxes-in-ag-grid

Answer (score 0):

As you say that you are using AdapTable then you can just add the name of the column to the `CheckBoxColumns` list in PredefinedConfig / UserInterface

See:  https://docs.adaptabletools.com/docs/predefined-config/user-interface-config#checkboxcolumns

So something like:

```
    export default {
        UserInterface: {
            CheckboxColumns: ['myBooleanColumn'],
        },
    } as PredefinedConfig;
```

That will dynamically create a CellRenderer very similar to the one which NearHuscarl suggests.

If the column is ReadOnly the checkboxes will be disabled.

Its worth noting that the CheckboxColumnClickedEvent will fire each time a cell in the column is clicked.